# android font in XML feature not working with AppWidget

Tags: android, android-widget

Android 8.0 (API level 26) introduces a new feature, **Fonts** in XML, which lets you use fonts as resources. as shown here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.

With this, I have successfully changed the font of the TextClock inside the activity but the above method is not working on AppWidget. AppWidget Still showing the system fonts.

here is my_app_widget.xml file...

```xml
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="@dimen/widget_margin">

     <TextClock
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:textColor="#8FFF"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:fontFamily="@font/opensans"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

is there any other method to change the TextClock fonts in AppWidget

Comment: you mean programmatically?

Comment: "the above method is not working on AppWidget" -- correct. Your app is not displaying an app widget. The launcher is displaying the app widget. The launcher does not contain your font.

Comment: @CommonsWare That seems...counter-intuitive? I mean, since the host is already pulling other resources from the app; e.g., the layout, drawables, etc. Indeed, in my quick and dirty test, [it seems to work as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKzZT.jpg).

Comment: @MikeM.: Yeah, I'm a moron. I was thinking in terms of fonts from assets, not resources. Sorry!

Comment: I don't have an answer to why it doesn't work but just going to add I wasn't able to achieve this either. ended up downloading a few fonts I wanted unfortunately.  you can check my very basic (also a TextClock) widget code here: https://github.com/y0av/MaterialClockWidget feel free to fork or pull request.

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/190444596

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the final answer to this problem, it won't get fixed in future this is google answer:

> This is an intended change. Allowing custom fonts in app widgets was
> an unintended behavior and could also expose a security bug. In june
> update we have fixed that flaw.